# Regular exp to find some special pattern

Tags: regex

i need to find out all the url in a url pool

let say the url pool contains

```
/a/a.html
/b/z.html  
/e/s-v.html  
/z2/s_v.html   
/b/d/s_v.html  
/b/e/s_v.html
```

i need to find out

```
/a/a.html
/b/z.html
/e/s-v.html
/z2/s_v.html
```

any regular pattern to do this? (my url pool actually have million different url, thus dont use `|` to do this)

Comment: Do you only want entries containing two '/' characters?

Comment: Any particular flavour, any language? I guess you can find tons of URL matching regexes here on SO.

Comment: i need to find out contains only 2 '/' characters and the first subfolder must be /a/, /b/, /e/ , /z2/

Comment: According to the your last comment. I updated my answer.

Comment: 44 questions and 9 answers and you are not able to format your posts??!! [formating help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 2):

This pattern will match it all:

```
 ^\/[abe]|z2\/[-a-z_]*\.html$
```

Comment: @user192344 sorry, Forgot the plus (+) sign.

Answer (score 1):

This filters out all urls with two `/` characters:

```
/^(?:\/[^\/]*){2}$/
```

**Edit**

Matching only /a/, /b/, /e/ & /z2/:

```
/^\/(?:a|b|e|z2)\/.*\.html$/
```

Comment: how about if i need to combine with some special text , such as /a/

Comment: @user192344 you don't want to match `/a/`?

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I came out with (using Linux standard grep):
^/([abe]\|z2)/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+.html$
It meets your requirements (first subfolder is exactly a,b,e, or z2), as long as between second / and html there are only letters, digits and _,-

Answer (score 0):

```
^([/][a-zA-Z0-9]*/[_-a-zA-Z0-9]*.html)
```

the conditions for a match are:

- first letter is a slash /
- first block is alphanumeric
- second block can contain - and _
- ends with .html

Answer (score -2):

actually i find a other way to do that

/+[a-zA-Z0-9]+/([\w]|[.]|[_]|[-])+.html

it match

/a/a.html

/a/a-a.html,/a/a-a-a.html

/a/a_a.html,/a/a_a_a.html

/a/a.a.html, /a/a.a.a.html

Comment: you didn't say anything about comma separated strings. next time specify your question a little bit more and don't just downvote everything!

Comment: 44 questions and 9 answers and you are not able to format your posts??!! [formating help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: And your own answer is worse than what you got from other posters here, it will match much more than what you expect.